# Changing my default internet connection

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

Im running openVPN on my Windows 10. I succesfuly connected the client to my VPN server as you can see:

[image]

But when I check my IP from my browser I still see the IP of my wifi connection. The openVPN client created a virtual devices VPN as you can see in the screenshoot, but for some reason, Windows is not using it.

Comment: You are running OpenVPN on the same machine you are connecting the client to? OpenVPN must be configured not to leak your DNS and ip address.

Comment: @Ramhound, no, my client and my server are two different machines.

Comment: The second part of my comment stands.  You must configured your server in such a way that your DNS and ip address isn't leaked.

Comment: @Ramhound can you point me to doucmentation about it?

Comment: I feel it is fair to early for me to research the problem.  I have given you key information required to follow existing tutorials to do it yourself.  You need to configure your OpenVPN server and client so it is operates/clients  as a Full Tunnel vs split-tunnel which means your information will be leaked.  Numerous questions that exist that talk about this concept.

Comment: @Domingo is your VPN server machine and your VPN client machine in your Home LAN ?